# Magento 2 product is "in stock" and saleable qty is zero 'add to cart' still showing in category page

Tags: magento2, product, category, catalog, inventory

Using Magento 2.3.5-p1 version

Product stock status is "in stock" and saleable qty is zero 'add to cart' still showing in category page

but the "add to cart" button not showing in the product details page which is perfect.

How to remove the "add to cart" button from the category listing page?

Comment: Please check after flush cache

Comment: already done cache clean,flush and index too

Comment: Are you allowing back orders on that product?

Comment: @MarkRees no back orders